# How to detect keypresses on a web browser

Tags: vbscript, keyboard-events, hta

I want to be able to detect a certain key press while I'm using a web browser (mainly Google Chrome) without using browser extensions. I'd like to do this with a program that's being executed outside of the browser (for example a `.vbs` or an  `.hta` file)

I found a code somewhere else that works pretty well, but it works in a predetermined, blank window instead of a browser window (It's an `.hta` program)

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

    Sub RunScript

        If window.event.Keycode = 13 Then

            Msgbox "You pressed the Enter key."

        End If

    End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<body onkeypress="RunScript">

</body>
```

I know similar questions have been asked multiple times but I wasn't able to find a single code that worked in a browser

Comment: _"[detect] key press while I'm using a web browser [by] a program that's being executed outside of the browser"_ this basically means you want a keylogger/hotkey program which only records keys when a specific process has user focus; whether it is a browser or anything else is irrelevant. Take a look at autohotkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think browsers no longer support VBScript afaik. It's pretty much a dead language. Try JavaScript.

Search for "Keyboard Events" on the following page:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: Do you know how to do this with JavaScript then? I'm asking this question mainly to find a working code,even if it's in JS

Comment: i added a link to my post showing you a place to get started that is easy.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out (hopefully) soon